# Java: WFSDatastore return the Features to be used in the main class

Tags: java, geotools

i am pretty new in Java Programming so i am thankfull for any help.
I am currently trying to get the Features of a WFS Datastore to be accessed in the another class of the project - for further retransforming the projection and displaying these features with processing.

with return wfsDSF i somehow can't access the features (lon, lat, date, time, rate..)

Printing the features in console already works for me.

here the code (except for url and featuresource):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStoreFactory;
import org.opengis.feature.Feature;


public class WFSConnector {

public static WFSDataStoreFactory wfsDSF () throws SQLException {

    // define the getCapabilities request
    String wfsGetCapabilitiesURL = "URL";

    // create WFSDataStoreFactory object
    WFSDataStoreFactory wfsDSF = new WFSDataStoreFactory();

    // create HashMap and fill it with connection parameters
    HashMap connectionParameters = new HashMap();
    connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.URL.key, wfsGetCapabilitiesURL);
    connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.TIMEOUT.key, 20000);

    try {
        WFSDataStore wfsDS = wfsDSF.createDataStore(connectionParameters);          
        SimpleFeatureSource sfSource = wfsDS.getFeatureSource("SELECTED-FEATURE");
        SimpleFeatureCollection sfCollection = sfSource.getFeatures();
        SimpleFeatureIterator sfIterator = sfCollection.features();          

       // check if the FeatureReader object holds another
       while(sfIterator.hasNext() == true)
       {
            //iterate through the "rows" of the WFS response
            Feature currentFeature = sfIterator.next();

            String coordinates = currentFeature.getProperty("the_geom").getValue().toString();
            String fphenomenon = currentFeature.getProperty("phenomenon").getValue().toString();
            String ftriptime = currentFeature.getProperty("tripTime").getValue().toString();
            String fheartrate = currentFeature.getProperty("heartrate").getValue().toString();

            //get rid of the name "point" and the brackets of the geometry string
            int x = coordinates.lastIndexOf('(');
            int y = coordinates.lastIndexOf(')');
            String coord = coordinates.substring(x+1, y);                

            //split the coordinates into 2 parts
            String[] splitcoordinates = coord.split(" ");
            String lon = splitcoordinates[0];
            String lat = splitcoordinates[1];

            //split phenomenon into date and time                                
            String date = fphenomenon.substring(0,10); 
            String time = fphenomenon.substring(11,19);  

            {
                System.out.println(lon  + " : " + lat + " : " + date + " : " + time + " : " + ftriptime + " : " + fheartrate);
            }
       }          
    } 
    catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
        }

    return wfsDSF;  

} // main
} // class
```

Comment: In general programming questions are better asked here

Answer (score 0):

You are heading in the right direction, but there are some easier methods to help with what you are trying to do. Usually, I would return the `FeatureCollection` to my main program to carry out the processing there.

So something like:

```
private SimpleFeatureCollection getFeatureCollection(String typeName) throws IOException {
   return dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName).getFeatures();
}

String typeName = "topp:states";
SimpleFeatureCollection features = me.getFeatureCollection(typeName);
try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = features.features()) {
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
    //[.......]
  }
}
```

is a common pattern. Note, unless forced to always use `SimpleFeatures` rather than generic ones. Then rather than complex string manipulation the attributes can be accessed as Java Objects with suitable casts.

```
    SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
    Geometry geom = (Geometry) f.getDefaultGeometry();
    double lat = geom.getCentroid().getY();
    double lon = geom.getCentroid().getX();
    String name = (String) f.getAttribute("STATE_NAME");
    String abbr = (String) f.getAttribute("STATE_ABBR");
    double people = (double) f.getAttribute("PERSONS");
    System.out.println(name + "\t(" + abbr + ")\t" + people + "\t(" + lat + "," + lon + ")");
```

Obviously, you are free to do whatever processing you want in this loop. For the geometry I took the `centroid` since I knew I had a polygon, if you have points then just call `.getX()` & `.getY()` on the point directly.

Here is the whole program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStoreFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;

public class GetWFSAttributes {
  DataStore dataStore = null;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String getCapabilities = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities";
    GetWFSAttributes me = new GetWFSAttributes(getCapabilities);
    String[] names = me.getTypeNames();
    for (String name : names) {
      SimpleFeatureType schema = me.getSchema(name);
      System.out.println(name + ":" + schema);
    }

    String typeName = "topp:states";
    SimpleFeatureCollection features = me.getFeatureCollection(typeName);
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = features.features()) {
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
        Geometry geom = (Geometry) f.getDefaultGeometry();
        double lat = geom.getCentroid().getY();
        double lon = geom.getCentroid().getX();
        String name = (String) f.getAttribute("STATE_NAME");
        String abbr = (String) f.getAttribute("STATE_ABBR");
        double people = (double) f.getAttribute("PERSONS");
        System.out.println(name + "\t(" + abbr + ")\t" + people + "\t(" + lat + "," + lon + ")");
      }
    }
  }

  private SimpleFeatureCollection getFeatureCollection(String typeName) throws IOException {
    return dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName).getFeatures();
  }

  private String[] getTypeNames() throws IOException {
    return dataStore.getTypeNames();
  }

  private SimpleFeatureType getSchema(String name) throws IOException {
    return dataStore.getSchema(name);
  }

  public GetWFSAttributes(String capabilities) {
    aquireDataStoreWFS(capabilities);
  }

  public void aquireDataStoreWFS(String capabilities) {
    if (dataStore == null) {
      try {
        Map<String, Serializable> connectionParameters = new HashMap<>();
        connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.URL.key, capabilities);
        dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connectionParameters);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```